# Access top level Nested Json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a large JSON file, which the number will incrementally change over time when it gets updated etc. For example each car is represented by a number first one starting with [0] up to [159] at current. With the code below I am able to access the individual parts from various cars. Thanks to the help of the comments.

I am unable to get the Image URI from the JSON in the same way. I get this error from this: `Notice: Undefined index:`

```
echo $car['Images']['ImageURI'];
```

Any help will be fully appreciated!

```
$response = json_decode($json_data, true);
            foreach ($response as $index => $car) {
                $car['BasicPrice'];
                $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'];
                $car['Colour'];
                $car['EngineNumber'];
                $car['EngineSize'];
                $car['FuelType']['FuelType'];
                $car['HasServiceHistory'];
                $car['IsNew'];
                $car['InternetPrice'];
                $car['IsReserved'];
                $car['Make']['Make'];
                $car['Model']['Model'];
                $car['Odometer'];
                $car['PhotoCount'];
                $car['PreviousOwners'];
                $car['RegistrationNumber'];
                $car['RetailPrice'];
                $car['Specification']['Doors'];
                $car['StockNumber'];
                $car['Transmission']['Transmission'];

            }

            if (!is_array($response) || empty($response)) {
                return false;
            }
```

This is the first Car [0] and follows the same.

```
array(159){
  [
    0
  ]=>array(42){
    [
      "BasicPrice"
    ]=>float(4995.83)[
      "BodyStyle"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        "BodyStyle"
      ]=>string(4)"3 DR"[
        "BodyStyle_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"4cf50fe2-8c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    }[
      "Colour"
    ]=>string(12)"Red 'n' Roll"[
      "DaysInStock"
    ]=>int(1021)[
      "DaysInStockGroup"
    ]=>int(1021)[
      "Discount"
    ]=>float(0)[
      "EngineNumber"
    ]=>string(15)"B12XER-19MV2339"[
      "EngineSize"
    ]=>int(1229)[
      "EstimatedDeliveryDate"
    ]=>string(19)"2016-11-04T00:00:00"[
      "FuelType"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        "FuelType"
      ]=>string(6)"Petrol"[
        "FuelType_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"9cd0d601-bb1f-409d-b04d-4255ff47dc85"
    }[
      "HasServiceHistory"
    ]=>bool(false)
    "Images": [
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 1,
                "Image_UID": "2088e32e-d46a-42c2-8412-3802743bcc06",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=1&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 2,
                "Image_UID": "590cdfa2-d791-4414-bbb4-e5fbe7a5ac80",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=2&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 3,
                "Image_UID": "038674d1-f32e-40ac-90bf-fad4d3b25e7f",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=3&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 4,
                "Image_UID": "9e4d36b0-7e9d-4159-9315-548e30835aa4",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=4&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 5,
                "Image_UID": "c3ad8b52-df16-4925-b8f2-6434a1d3ece6",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=5&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 6,
                "Image_UID": "b5e66c41-a76e-4cd2-a535-623715e19961",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=6&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 7,
                "Image_UID": "6ce8cb63-4cee-4451-abd6-abc367d9f1d2",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=7&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 8,
                "Image_UID": "7b5ecc82-b8ea-4af4-85d6-1ab13c527edf",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=8&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 9,
                "Image_UID": "a1b2dae3-342f-4917-b7d8-6d9135bb8966",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=9&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 10,
                "Image_UID": "a6e1fce8-7bf9-4570-898b-91aa368c889d",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=10&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 11,
                "Image_UID": "0587afe6-4d95-4ce3-b571-0c1bc894516f",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=11&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 12,
                "Image_UID": "5b4713c8-37c9-4702-937c-4938c95bbee9",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=12&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 13,
                "Image_UID": "6c6a83d9-0782-42c6-a1fe-2d14272c7832",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=13&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 14,
                "Image_UID": "6e8a2171-e85a-4afd-a4fb-e70eeab38d10",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=14&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 15,
                "Image_UID": "f60e84ab-91bf-494d-9a54-0ad27615135a",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=15&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            },
            {
                "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
                "ImageNumber": 16,
                "Image_UID": "bfe311ca-4a62-4518-b27f-4d1473386741",
                "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=16&Width=960",
                "ImageWidth": 960
            }[
      "Interior"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        "Interior"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "Interior_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"05f50fe2-8c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    }[
      "IsNew"
    ]=>bool(false)[
      "InternetPrice"
    ]=>float(0)[
      "IsQualifying"
    ]=>bool(true)[
      "IsReserved"
    ]=>bool(false)[
      "Location"
    ]=>string(9)"Autospray"[
      "Make"
    ]=>array(3){
      [
        "FranchiseModel"
      ]=>NULL[
        "Make"
      ]=>string(8)"Vauxhall"[
        "Make_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"ac84ccae-882d-e611-80ca-0a94ef0355af"
    }[
      "ManufacturerRecommendedRetailPrice"
    ]=>float(0)[
      "Model"
    ]=>array(3){
      [
        "Make_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"ac84ccae-882d-e611-80ca-0a94ef0355af"[
        "Model"
      ]=>string(4)"Adam"[
        "Model_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"cb34d5c0-5c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    }[
      "Odometer"
    ]=>int(13582)[
      "Options"
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
      "OrganisationalUnit"
    ]=>array(6){
      [
        "Address"
      ]=>array(7){
        [
          "Address1"
        ]=>string(17)"Blackhouse Circle"[
          "Address2"
        ]=>string(28)"Blackhouse Industrial Estate"[
          "Address3"
        ]=>string(0)""[
          "Country"
        ]=>NULL[
          "County"
        ]=>string(8)"Aberdeen"[
          "PostCode"
        ]=>string(8)"AB42 1BN"[
          "PostTown"
        ]=>string(9)"Peterhead"
      }[
        "Description"
      ]=>string(22)"Gillanders Motors Ltd."[
        "EmailAddress"
      ]=>string(22)"email@gillanders.co.uk"[
        "OrganisationalUnit_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af"[
        "ParentOrganisationalUnit_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"51a9312b-1462-4b7c-aee3-319d6d86ecec"[
        "Telephone"
      ]=>string(12)"01779 479777"
    }[
      "PhotoCount"
    ]=>int(16)[
      "PhysicalLocation"
    ]=>array(5){
      [
        "DealerCode"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "Description"
      ]=>string(22)"Gillanders Motors Ltd."[
        "LocationDescription"
      ]=>string(9)"Autospray"[
        "OrganisationalUnit"
      ]=>array(6){
        [
          "Address"
        ]=>array(7){
          [
            "Address1"
          ]=>string(17)"Blackhouse Circle"[
            "Address2"
          ]=>string(28)"Blackhouse Industrial Estate"[
            "Address3"
          ]=>string(0)""[
            "Country"
          ]=>NULL[
            "County"
          ]=>string(8)"Aberdeen"[
            "PostCode"
          ]=>string(8)"AB42 1BN"[
            "PostTown"
          ]=>string(9)"Peterhead"
        }[
          "Description"
        ]=>string(22)"Gillanders Motors Ltd."[
          "EmailAddress"
        ]=>string(22)"email@gillanders.co.uk"[
          "OrganisationalUnit_UID"
        ]=>string(36)"a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af"[
          "ParentOrganisationalUnit_UID"
        ]=>string(36)"51a9312b-1462-4b7c-aee3-319d6d86ecec"[
          "Telephone"
        ]=>string(12)"01779 479777"
      }[
        "UID"
      ]=>string(36)"a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af"
    }[
      "PreviousOwners"
    ]=>int(0)[
      "Profiles"
    ]=>array(1){
      [
        0
      ]=>array(2){
        [
          "Description"
        ]=>string(14)"Long Term Loan"[
          "UID"
        ]=>string(36)"fe8b7140-87e0-4784-88b1-d607865be492"
      }
    }[
      "RegistrationDate"
    ]=>string(19)"2016-10-31T00:00:00"[
      "RegistrationNumber"
    ]=>string(8)"SW66 EZH"[
      "RetailPrice"
    ]=>float(5995)[
      "Specification"
    ]=>array(3){
      [
        "Doors"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "Specification"
      ]=>string(3)"Jam"[
        "Specification_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"8795a7e0-e1a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af"
    }[
      "Status"
    ]=>int(0)[
      "StockNumber"
    ]=>string(5)"U1211"[
      "Transmission"
    ]=>array(2){
      [
        "Transmission"
      ]=>string(21)"5 Speed Manual Petrol"[
        "Transmission_UID"
      ]=>string(36)"707ad700-1318-4e57-88aa-6fb19e58f6d0"
    }[
      "UnitOfDistance"
    ]=>int(0)[
      "Vehicle_UID"
    ]=>string(36)"8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af"[
      "VehicleCode"
    ]=>string(40)"VAAD12JAM3HPIM "[
      "VehicleType"
    ]=>int(1)[
      "VideoCount"
    ]=>int(1)[
      "Videos"
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
      "VIN"
    ]=>string(17)"W0L0MAP08G6082024"
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure  I understood you correctly. Do you want a "function" that print info about one car for applying it on whole list?

Comment: Apologies yes I would like to be able to print info about all the cars, being applied throughout the whole list. I will have to replicate this process for each criteria - skipping out UID's

Answer (score 0):

The JSON will almost certainly be returning an array of vehicles, once it's parsed it is just like any other array which you can iterate, and you can completely ignore the index by using foreach:

```
$response = json_decode($json_data, true);
foreach ($response as $index => $car) { 
    echo $car['BasicPrice'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'];  
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate that! Solved my problem thanks @MarkRandall

Comment: Hi Mark, Your code worked beautifully, however now the company has told me I have to have these Images which I have updated in the JSON response. Problem is I cannot seem to access them in the same way. Any way you would be able to have a look for me please?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest example:
The function `array_map` applied your custom function to every item in $response.

```php
array_map(function ($car) {
   echo car['BasicPrice'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'];
   echo "<br>";
}, $response);
```